# Kubernetes secret programmatically update

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-secrets

Is there a way to programmatically update a kubernetes secret from a pod? that is, not using kubectl.
I have a secret mounted on a pod and also exposed via an environment variable. I would like to modify it from my service but it looks that it's read only by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Kubernetes REST API with the pod's serviceaccount's token as credentials (found at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` inside the pod), you just need to allow the service account to edit secrets in the namespace via a role.

See [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/secret-v1/) for the API docs

The API server is internally reachable via https://kubernetes.default